extracting text from webscraping
I'm trying to get text from a website
My code works (sort of)
for (i in 1:no_urls) {
  this_url=urls_meetings[[i]]
  page=read_html(this_url)
  
  text=page |> html_elements("body") |> html_text2()
  text_date=text[1]
  date<- str_extract(text_date, "\\b\\w+ \\d{1,2}, \\d{4}\\b")
  # Convert the abbreviated month name to its full form
  date_str <- gsub("^(.*)\\s(\\d{1,2}),\\s(\\d{4})$", "\\1 \\2, \\3", date)

  # Convert to Date object
  date <- mdy(date_str)
  date_1=as.character(date)
  date_1=gsub("-", "", date_1)


  text=text[2]
  statements_list2[[i]]=text
  names(statements_list)[i] <- date_1

}


The problem is the output if the line
text=page |> html_elements("body") |> html_text2()

which gives me the entire text of the page
[1] "\r \r\r \r\nRelease Date: January 29, 2003\r\n\n\n\n\n\r For immediate release\r\n\n\r\n\n\r\r\n\n\r The Federal Open Market Committee decided today to keep its target for the federal funds rate unchanged at 1-1/4 percent. \r\n\n\r Oil price premiums and other aspects of geopolitical risks have reportedly fostered continued restraint on spending and hiring by businesses. However, the Committee believes that as those risks lift, as most analysts expect, the accommodative stance of monetary policy, coupled with ongoing growth in productivity, will provide support to an improving economic climate over time.\r\n\n\r In these circumstances, the Committee believes that, against the background of its long-run goals of price stability and sustainable economic growth and of the information currently available, the risks are balanced with respect to the prospects for both goals for the foreseeable future. \r\n\n\r Voting for the FOMC monetary policy action were Alan Greenspan, Chairman; William J. McDonough, Vice Chairman; Ben S. Bernanke, Susan S. Bies; J. Alfred Broaddus, Jr.; Roger W. Ferguson, Jr.; Edward M. Gramlich; Jack Guynn; Donald L. Kohn; Michael H. Moskow; Mark W. Olson, and Robert T. Parry. \r \r \r\n\n\r -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\r DO NOT REMOVE: Wireless Generation\r ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\r 2003 Monetary policy \r\n\nHome | News and \r events\nAccessibility\r\n\r Last update: January 29, 2003\r\r \r\n(function(){if (!document.body) return;var js = \"window['__CF$cv$params']={r:'8775c6b49a2a2015',t:'MTcxMzYyMjgzOC41MjIwMDA='};_cpo=document.createElement('script');_cpo.nonce='',_cpo.src='/cdn-cgi/challenge-platform/scripts/jsd/main.js',document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(_cpo);\";var _0xh = document.createElement('iframe');_0xh.height = 1;_0xh.width = 1;_0xh.style.position = 'absolute';_0xh.style.top = 0;_0xh.style.left = 0;_0xh.style.border = 'none';_0xh.style.visibility = 'hidden';document.body.appendChild(_0xh);function handler() {var _0xi = _0xh.contentDocument || _0xh.contentWindow.document;if (_0xi) {var _0xj = _0xi.createElement('script');_0xj.innerHTML = js;_0xi.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(_0xj);}}if (document.readyState !== 'loading') {handler();} else if (window.addEventListener) {document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', handler);} else {var prev = document.onreadystatechange || function () {};document.onreadystatechange = function (e) {prev(e);if (document.readyState !== 'loading') {document.onreadystatechange = prev;handler();}};}})();"



I need to keep only the relevant text. I've tried all sorts of things
str_extract(text, "(?<=The Federal Open Market)(.*?)(?=Voting)")


 str_match(text, "The Federal Open Market(.*?)Voting")

but they all give me a null character in return
The ideal output is
The Federal Open Market Committee decided today to keep its target for the federal funds rate unchanged at 1-1/4 percent. \r\n\n\r Oil price premiums and other aspects of geopolitical risks have reportedly fostered continued restraint on spending and hiring by businesses. However, the Committee believes that as those risks lift, as most analysts expect, the accommodative stance of monetary policy, coupled with ongoing growth in productivity, will provide support to an improving economic climate over time.\r\n\n\r In these circumstances, the Committee believes that, against the background of its long-run goals of price stability and sustainable economic growth and of the information currently available, the risks are balanced with respect to the prospects for both goals for the foreseeable future.



You need to define “relevant”. You know what you mean. We don’t.

Could you please specify the desired result for that site? It does not include "Voting" so your regex can't get a match.

The . character does not match new lines by default
The reason your pattern isn't working is because you have new lines in your string. The definition of the . metacharacter is that it matches any character except a newline.
Here's a shorter example:
txt <- "there are some\r\nwords here"
str_extract(txt, "some.+words")
# [1] NA

Override the defaults
To override the defaults in stringr::str_extract(), you need to use stringr::regex() with the relevant option. In this case,

You can allow . to match everything, including \n, by setting dotall = TRUE:

str_extract(txt, regex("some.+words", dotall = TRUE))
# [1] "some\r\nwords"

Or in the case of your string:
str_extract(text, regex("(?<=The Federal Open Market)(.*?)(?=Voting)", dotall = TRUE))  |> 
    trimws()
# [1] "Committee decided today to keep its target for the federal funds rate unchanged at 1-1/4 percent. \r\n\n\r Oil price premiums and other aspects of geopolitical risks have reportedly fostered continued restraint on spending and hiring by businesses. However, the Committee believes that as those risks lift, as most analysts expect, the accommodative stance of monetary policy, coupled with ongoing growth in productivity, will provide support to an improving economic climate over time.\r\n\n\r In these circumstances, the Committee believes that, against the background of its long-run goals of price stability and sustainable economic growth and of the information currently available, the risks are balanced with respect to the prospects for both goals for the foreseeable future."

I have also passed this to trimws() to remove the leading and trailing whitespace.
Other multi line options
If you want to generally extend your regular expressions to match multiple lines (and not just the . metacharacter), you can use regex(pattern, multiline = TRUE):

For multiline strings, you can use regex(multiline = TRUE). This changes the behaviour of ^ and $, and introduces three new operators:

^ now matches the start of each line.
$ now matches the end of each line.
\A matches the start of the input.
\z matches the end of the input.
\Z matches the end of the input, but before the final line terminator, if it exists.


See the stringr docs for more.

Looking at the html, it looks like you can extract just the table:
this_url <- "https://www.federalreserve.gov/boarddocs/press/general/2002/20020130/"
page=read_html(this_url)

text=page |> html_elements("table") |> html_text() |> trimws()

And just get this:

[1] "The Federal Open Market Committee decided today to keep its
target for the federal funds rate unchanged at 1-3/4
percent.\r\n\r\nSigns that weakness in demand is abating and economic
activity is beginning to firm have become more prevalent.  With the
forces restraining the economy starting to diminish, and with the
long-term prospects for productivity growth remaining favorable and
monetary policy accommodative, the outlook for economic recovery has
become more promising.\r\n\r\nThe degree of any strength in business
capital and household spending, however, is still uncertain.  Hence,
the Committee continues to believe that, against the background of its
long-run goals of price stability and sustainable economic growth and
of the information currently available, the risks are weighted mainly
toward conditions that may generate economic weakness in the
foreseeable future.\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n2002 Monetary policy \r\n\r\nHome
|\r\nNews and events\r\nAccessibility\r\n\r\nLast update: January 30,
2002"

Or separate the paragraphs with this:
page |> html_elements("table p") |> html_text() |> trimws()


Assuming the structure is more or less stable, you can specify which positional paragraphs to include / exclude.
library(rvest)
library(stringr)

# list of urls
urls_ <- c("https://www.federalreserve.gov/boarddocs/press/general/2002/20020130/")

collect_text <- function(url_){
  html <- read_html(url_)
  
  release_date <- 
    html_element(html, "body > font > i") |> 
    html_text() |> 
    str_split_i(": ", 2) |> 
    lubridate::mdy()
  
  text <- 
    # all p elements in td, except the last one
    html_elements(html, "td > p:not(p:last-of-type)") |> 
    html_text(trim = TRUE) |> 
    str_c(collapse = "") |>
    str_squish()

  # reurn named list
  list(release_date = release_date, text = text)
}

df <- 
  lapply(urls_, collect_text) |>
  dplyr::bind_rows()
df  
#> # A tibble: 1 × 2
#>   release_date text                                                             
#>   <date>       <chr>                                                            
#> 1 2002-01-30   The Federal Open Market Committee decided today to keep its targ…

str_view(df[1,"text"])
#> [1] │ The Federal Open Market Committee decided today to keep its target for the federal funds rate unchanged at 1-3/4 percent.Signs that weakness in demand is abating and economic activity is beginning to firm have become more prevalent. With the forces restraining the economy starting to diminish, and with the long-term prospects for productivity growth remaining favorable and monetary policy accommodative, the outlook for economic recovery has become more promising.The degree of any strength in business capital and household spending, however, is still uncertain. Hence, the Committee continues to believe that, against the background of its long-run goals of price stability and sustainable economic growth and of the information currently available, the risks are weighted mainly toward conditions that may generate economic weakness in the foreseeable future.

